# How to split a value of a hashmap with freemarker?

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, hashmap, freemarker

I have a hash map as below :

```
gfpFileBean.getChaines().put("IN-RDU", "GFPZ001Q;OK" );     
gfpFileBean.getChaines().put("IN-PLEIADES", "GFPZ003Q;OK" );
```

My Freemarker template is :

```
<#list gfpVb.chaines as key,value> 
                   <td>
                   <strong>${key}</strong>                                
                   </td>
                   <td>
                   <strong>${value}</strong>
</#list>
```

I would like to know if it is possible to split the value of hashmap with freemarker, to display the value where I want it in the table.

Comment: what do mean by "split the value of hashmap"? can you please explain  bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a value to a list of values with `someValue?split(someSeparator)`, so:

```
<#list gfpVb.chaines as key, value> 
  <td>
    <strong>${key}</strong>                                
  </td>
  <#list value?split(';') as columnValue>
    <td>
      <strong>${columnValue}</strong>
    </td>
  </#list>
</#list>
```

But it's generally better practice to ensure that the value is already split in the data-model.